# Player doesn't respond or presents just picture in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c

IOS app calling url video file but no player to see the video.
[debug screen is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNnfm.png)

```
  if([_mServiceID isEqualToString:@"movFilePlay"] == YES)
    {
        NSString* path = [StandardPlugin.FCM_URL stringByAppendingString:[dic strValueForKey:@"filePath"]];
        //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]bundlePath];
        NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        AVPlayer *player =[AVPlayer playerWithURL:filePath];
        UIPageViewController *controller= [[UIPageViewController alloc]init];
        //controller.player = player;
        
        [self.playerViewController addChildViewController:controller];
       // controller.player = player;
        [player play];
```

when I press the file to open video loads for a second and player will disappear. Please help me thanks!
[Iphone creen there is tiny picture of video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB2Ed.jpg)

Comment: It's a remote URL? Then `fileURLWithPath` should `[NSURL URLWithString: path]` You might want to check the `status` for potential errors

Comment: I tried with  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"filePath" ofType:@"mp4"];     but didn't work :(

Comment: there is no error. I uploaded debug sceen too. Check it out.

Comment: @Larme it sees file but doesn't play it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

HTML5 video tag -> loop muted autoplay playsinline

Just added these codes in web page in video tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
//  找的链接，可能已过期
NSString* onlineVideoFilePathStr = @"http://vodkgeyttp9.vod.126.net/vodkgeyttp8/pLe5UjdH_7088357_hd.mp4?wsSecret=3407504c27d588bd72f45562e491ef19&wsTime=1559208462&ext=NnR5gMvHcZNcbCz592mDGUGuDOFN18isir07K1EOfL3DA%2FLg%2FvnQozcajtXTmTYynMXslak4S5ceCtQtxSBm80drT0XNo7yBQA%2FXVpOSilHsKsAGdInnG51QYQ7oEjcAhYcDl8crv%2Fb%2FDUIrVdVC5nHgE0%2FmBeAQblajNfkskgDcbRj2543qIHELWaYB6Yvxn5x%2BlNAmBadQ%2FibVtO3RJTx6xTwPSZnvT7ipiNC1OU83ohkF0TdctDfYv6C69xA1";
NSURL* videoUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:onlineVideoFilePathStr];

AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:videoUrl];
_player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

[self.player play];
```

Comment: Those codes won't work for me anyway thanks!

Comment: It seems like problem is not the app side. I found something like solution but I am not really sure about that. I am embedding from webview so there might be something wrong with HTTML5 video tag. I've checked video tag there is no playsinline muted loop and also app worked when low power mode is turned on.